# $CI is not available in function php

Tags: php, codeigniter

not sure if this is already answered, but i cant seem to find the right answer to my question

I am creating a library, and my library is using an existing model. i am having trouble using the $CI outside the __construct.

here is a snippet of my code.

```
class something-todo {

protected $CI;

public function __construct(){
    $this->$CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->model('Sites');  
}

public function get_records()
{
    $results = $CI->Sites->get_activeRecords();
 // other lines of code
 }
```

whenever i am calling this library, I am getting a $CI error inside the get_records() function.

not sure what else to do.

thank if this is a duplicate, thank for the redirect. otherwise, thank in advance for any answer.

Comment: Use $this->CI  instead of $CI

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because you create instance

```
 $this->$CI =& get_instance();
```

and you use

```
 $CI->load->model('Sites'); // it is $this->$CI
```

Write way of creating instance how it is use

```
  $this->CI =& get_instance();
```

so your code will be

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->model('Sites');  
}


public function get_records()
{
    $results = $this->CI->Sites->get_activeRecords();
 // other lines of code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this key word to access $IC, and use the below code:

```
class something-todo {

protected $CI;

public function __construct(){
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->model('Sites');  
}

public function get_records()
{
    $results = $this->CI->Sites->get_activeRecords();
 // other lines of code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class something-todo {

protected $CI;

public function __construct(){
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->model('Sites');  
}

public function get_records()
{
    $results = $this->CI->Sites->get_activeRecords();
 // other lines of code
 }
```

Use this piece of code